# Poisson process with uniformly distributed random variables

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, poisson-process

Assume a Poisson process $\{N(t),t\geq0\}$ with rate $\frac{1}{12}$, where $t$ is a random variable that is uniformly distributed over $(2,4)$. Then how to find $P(N(t)=0)$?

So I started with assuming $t=3$, then I know $P(N(3)=0)=e^{-\frac{1}{12}\cdot3}\frac{\left(\frac{1}{12}\cdot3\right)^0}{0!}=e^{-\frac{1}{4}}$. But how should I deal with uniformly distributed random variables?

Comment: Law of total probability gives $P(N_T=0)=\int_2^4 P(N_T=0 |T=t)f_T(t) \mathrm{dt}$ where $T\sim U(2,4)$, and $f_T$ is the PDF of $T$. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 How do you find $P(N_T=0\mid T=t)$?

Comment: Conditional on $T=t$, $N_T=N_t$ is Poisson distributed with mean $\lambda t$. So $P(N_T=0|T=t)=P(N_t=0)$. Is that clear now?

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure how to compute $P(N_t=0)$ with $t$ uniformly distributed...

Comment: you are completely ignoring or not registering what I am saying: *Conditional on* $T=t$ the RV $N_T=N_t$ *is Poisson distributed with mean* $\lambda t$. Thus $P(N_T=0|T=t)=P(N_t=0)$, where $t\in (2,4)$ is *conditionally a constant*. You should *know* how to compute probabilities of any Poisson RV, i.e. $P(N_t=j)=\frac{(\lambda t)^j}{j!}e^{-\lambda t}$.

Comment: Then multiplying by the PDF of $T$ and integrating over $(2,4)$ yields the probability $P(N_T=0)$ by the *law of total probability*. Pay careful attention to the *standard convention* of using *uppercase letters* for RVs and *lowercase letters* for the values they take on, when conditioning or otherwise.

Comment: To hopefully make things as clear as possible: in your question, you already computed $P(N_T=0| T=3)=P(N_3=0)$. Now, just compute the same but conditioning on the event $T=t$ instead.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 Oh I get it now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use conditional expectation, $$P(N(t) = 0) = E[ P(N(t) = 0 \, | \, t) ]\,.$$